# IDE / setup for package development with C++ code integrated

Tags: c++, r, ide, package, rcpp

I'm trying to get a grip on C++/Rcpp as an extension to R for heavy computational tasks. Ultimately, these C++ libs should be integrated in a package, and therefor I'm looking for a setup / combination of tools / IDE that I would need to work easily. I know much is taste dependent, but still it would be nice to know my options before choosing.

So : when you develop R packages with C++ libs, what is the setup you work with?

- do you use the same editor / IDE for R and C++ and which one (or which ones) ?
- are there extra tools (apart from Rtools) that are important to get ?
- are there tweaks in the general setup that are important to know or speed up the process considerably?

Sorry if this question has been asked before. I found a list of all editors for R, but nothing specifically directed towards developing of packages including C++ code. Any hints or tips are really appreciated.

Edit : platform is Windows, but I can move to Linux without problems (dual boot, only thing keeping me from using ubuntu is the lack of a decent driver for my old card/old screen combination)

Comment: What platform?  Windows, guessing from Rtools?

Comment: You could swap one of the tags 'ide' and 'development' for 'rcpp'.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Eclipse + [statet](http://www.walware.de/goto/statet) if you want to join in us in the modern world :)

Comment: @Dr G: I've tried it, but I wasn't convinced about Eclipse/StatET for using R. I use Tinn-R, and that's -for R- still the best to my taste. But I'll give it a try again with C++

Comment: Serves the purpose indeed, although I keep on using Tinn-R when I work with R alone.

Comment: I used to swap between statet and sciViews, but statet is actively developed and features are being added regularly. I find that once you get used to it it's a great work environment...

Comment: I'm late to the party, but getting eclipse up and running with Rcpp is a non-trival task. Here is something to get you started: http://blog.fellstat.com/?p=170

Comment: @IanFellows You should post a separate answer of your own. I can't imagine how difficult it would be for me to setup Eclipse + Statet + Rcpp without your article. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 3):

I'm of course fully in favour of more [Rcpp](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp.html) work :)

As for your questions, and in order:

- same editor (Emacs) which makes for nice consistency on either platform I use (mostly Linux, occassionally Windows); for the record I have also spoke out in favour of the `qtcreator` IDE which is pretty nice on Linux and Windows (but doesn't do R).
- no, on Linux it all comes ready made (and yes, on Windows you do need Rtools) ...
- not really -- you probably already know about [inline](http://cran.r-project.org/package=inline) which is good for testing R/C++ code snippets.

*Edit:* So in a way, this is really no different from normal R / C / C++ / Fortran development.  And in that case I usually refer to [R FAQ Section 6](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#R-and-Emacs) which is devoted entirely to R and Emacs :)
With that said, setting Emacs up for C++ work is not obvious and there are a number of questions and posts here.  I do not use any particular class browser but there are some, as well as approaches to auto-completion of types etc.

Comment: Windows it is, sorry for not mentioning it. and thx for the pointer to inline. Heard about it before from a certain sir Eddelbuettel, but forgot about it again.

Comment: Yes, if and when you have Windows itself tamed with Rtools, the right path, maybe latex, .... then the choice of editor is simple.  Pick one that feels right.  Some folks also swear by Eclipse for both C++ and R (using a plugin called StatET for R).

Answer (score 2):

You will want an editor that can handle multiple languages, R, C+, maybe Makefiles, etc.  Since you mention Rtools it sounds like you are on Windows.  I would suggest Notepad++ it handles R, C++, and a whole lot of other languages.  Plus you can setup custom command through NppExec to build the package more easily.  I have developed a few packages that make heavy use of C/C++ using Notepad++.

Answer (score 1):

I just wrote a cmake script to generate Eclipse CDT project for developing Rcpp package.

Moreover, cmake might be able to generate CodeBlocks or KDevelop3 projects, but I have not
checked these features, yet.

## Environment

- CMake >= 2.8.7
- Eclipse >= 3.7
- Eclipse CDT >= 1.4.2
- R >= 2.15
- Rcpp >= 0.10

## Configuration

- Download FindLibR.cmake from [github](https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/blob/master/cmake/modules/FindLibR.cmake) 
  provided by Rstudio
- Generate Rcpp package, for example

  ```
  library(Rcpp)
  Rcpp.package.skeleton("RcppPackage")
  ```
- Put the following script (or download it from [gist](https://gist.github.com/4662585)), named *CMakeLists.txt*, in the generated folder
  such as `RcppPackage` in the previous example.

  ```
  cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
  project(RcppPackage)
  find_package(LibR)
  if(${LIBR_FOUND})
  else()
      message(FATAL_ERROR "No R...")
  endif()
  message(STATUS ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR})
  execute_process(
      COMMAND ${LIBR_EXECUTABLE} "--slave" "-e" "stopifnot(require('Rcpp'));cat(Rcpp:::Rcpp.system.file('include'))"
      OUTPUT_VARIABLE LIBRCPP_INCLUDE_DIRS
  ) 
  include_directories(BEFORE ${LIBR_INCLUDE_DIRS})
  message(STATUS ${LIBR_INCLUDE_DIRS})
  include_directories(BEFORE ${LIBRCPP_INCLUDE_DIRS})
  message(STATUS ${LIBRCPP_INCLUDE_DIRS})
  add_custom_target(RcppPackage ALL
      COMMAND find ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR} -name "*.o" -exec rm "{}" "\;"
      COMMAND find ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR} -name "*.so" -exec rm "{}" "\;"
      COMMAND ${LIBR_EXECUTABLE} "--slave" "-e" "\"stopifnot(require(roxygen2));roxygenize('${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}',roclets=c('rd','collate','namespace'))\""
      COMMAND ${LIBR_EXECUTABLE} CMD INSTALL "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}")
  ```
- Customize `roxygenize` and `R CMD INSTALL` in *CMakeLists.txt*
- Generate project with cmake

  ```
  mkdir build # don't create subdirectory of RcppPackage
  cd build
  cmake -G "Eclipse CDT4 - Unix Makefiles" <path to RcppPackage> -DCMAKE_ECLIPSE_GENERATE_SOURCE_PROJECT=TRUE
  ```
- Open eclipse and import project from `build`(See [cmake-eclipse-cdt](http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/Eclipse_CDT4_Generator) for example). 
  After indexing, enjoy several convenient features provided by Eclipse CDT 
  such as tracing and autocomplete.
- You can build the project which will be converted to `R CMD INSTALL` or
  anything in the *CMakeLists.txt*.